# Having trouble rotating vectors in Unity with Quaternions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to C#, and have a beginner level background in Python and Java. I'm using Unity trying to make a 2d game with a portal gun and portal-esque physics (think Valve's portal series).

Currently have two portals that work by teleporting you to the other portal. When my player enters a portal, I want their velocity to be 'rotated' for when they pop out the other portal. [image: Example of what I'm aiming for.]

Trying to use [quaternions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) to achieve this, but it's going terribly. Here is my full code:-

Portal Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Portal : MonoBehaviour
{

public bool activated = false;
public Portal portalOut;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
    if(!activated)
    {
        portalOut.activated = true;
        col.gameObject.transform.position = portalOut.gameObject.transform.position;
    }
    activated = false;
    }

}
```

Player Movement Script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float speed = 8f;
    private float jumpingPower = 8f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb; 
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
        }
        
    }
    
    // Framerate independent physic calculations
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        
        //Portal
        bool isGreenActivated = GameObject.Find("BluePortal").GetComponent<Portal>().activated;  //PortalOut of BluePortal (GreenPortal) is activated once someone triggers BluePortal.
        if(isGreenActivated == true) //If player goes into portal
        {
            Debug.Log("Activated");
            rb.velocity = ConvertVelocity(rb.velocity);
        }
    }

    public Vector3 ConvertVelocity(Vector2 initialVelocity)
    {
        GameObject outPortal = GameObject.Find("BluePortal"); //BluePortal OUT PORTAL
        GameObject inPortal = GameObject.Find("GreenPortal"); // GreenPortal IN PORTAL
        Quaternion conversion = Quaternion.FromToRotation(inPortal.transform.forward, -outPortal.transform.forward);
        Vector2 newVelocity = conversion * initialVelocity;
        return newVelocity;
    }
}
```

In the movement script, I'm having it check when my player enters a portal, and then having it's rb.velocity = ConvertVelocity(rb.velocity).

In ConvertVelocity(), I'm trying to use Quaternion conversion = Quaternion.FromToRotation() to check the direction of my portals and create the rotation, and then I do conversion * initialVelocity to find my new Vector2.

Currently when my player jumps into the Green portal, the player is spat out going upwards, instead of to the right. If the player jumps into the Green portal from under it, going into it upwards, the player is spat out going downwards. Have also tried Quaternion.AngleAxis(), but when I try to use it, nothing happens.

I would use it like so:

```
public Vector3 ConvertVelocity(Vector2 initialVelocity)
    {
        Quaternion conversion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector2.right);
        Vector2 newVelocity = conversion * initialVelocity;
        return newVelocity;
    }
```

Rotating the blue portal does nothing. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know your portal's facing (assuming the portal's "face" is the blue local axis, it's forward), so you can add velocity directly, like:

```
float originalVelocityMagnitude = _rigibody.velocity.magnitude;
// placing stuff
_rigidbody.velocity = teleportTransform.forward * originalVelocityMagnitude;
```

Vector3.forward is the global blue axis (normalized)

transform.forward is the transform's local forward vector in global (normalized)

Comment: This sort of works, but it only pushes my character a slight pixel to the right when I implement it. Any idea why my character would give up moving to the right after a split second?

Comment: Because of `rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);`. If there is no input, `horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");` evaluates to 0, and in the next FixedUpdate velocity will be overwritten. Better to use Rigidbody.AddForce than directly add value to Rigidbody.velocity.

Comment: Also using GameObject.Find in `Update`/`Fixedupdate` or in any method what called frequently is not a good practice (performance). Save the references in the class and use them instead.